# C# - match many cases in a single run

Tags: c#, asp.net

So the case is this:

The user can provide a group of strings for a propert. ex:

```
DaysNeeded ="Sunday,Tuesday,Friday,Saturday";
```

In the actual UI, the days of the week are available as check boxes. I'm trying to provide a way so that the user can also set the days needed in the code behind through a property.

Now my query is, which strategy is the best way to execute certain pieces of code that are respective to the days that the user have provided. Meaning, the DaysNeeded property has sunday,Tuesday, Friday and Saturday. Each day has certain piece of code  to be executed. If i have to have a forloop with a switch case for each day of the week, i feel it would cost more as i have to run the for loop, the number of days the user has given.

Is there a way that i can run a single code that matches all the set of days the user has given and run the respective code pieces?

Please let me know if I'm not clear with my query.

Comment: no matter how you construct the code it will end up being run in some kind of loop. Maybe its not obvious, but even *new List<string>(DaysNeeded.Split(',')).ForEach(d => dosomething(d))* will behind the curtain do some loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running four -- or more -- iterations of a `for` loop isn't going to be a problem, but it's unnecessary.

```
if (DaysNeeded.Contains("Sunday"))
    DoSundayWork();

if (DaysNeeded.Contains("Tuesday"))
    DoTuesdayWork();

if (DaysNeeded.Contains("Friday"))
    DoFridayWork();

if (DaysNeeded.Contains("Saturday"))
    DoSaturdayWork();
```

By the way, it would probably make more sense to use a [`Flags`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) for your `DaysNeeded` property rather than a comma-delimited string.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<string, Action> actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>() {
   {"Monday", e=> ...},
   ...
   {"Sunday", e=> ...}

}

foreach (var day in actions.Keys ) {
 if (DaysNeeded.Contains(day) {
   actions[day].Invoke()
 }
}
```

Maybe you like that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As a learner i too want to know if using dictionary action lookup would be the cost effective way of handling this scenario? Please share your thoughts?

Comment: The dictionary lookup is effectively free, the cost here is you still have a loop and you still have a contains operation. It should be stressed though that until performance becomes a problem your priority should be *correctness* from which maintenance and readability should flow. Don't micro optimise.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but would it work if you write your switch statement without breaks.

e.g.

```
switch(condition)
{
  case "Monday":
     ...
  case "Tuesday":
     ...
}
```

Comment: C# requires breaks or goto's - no true fallthrough, and the case statements will be matched against the result of condition, not individually matching conditions. A series of `if` statements is really the only suitable way, but that's perfectly valid.